# Calculate $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x-1)}{2^{x}}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I can prove it converges but I don't know at what value it converges.
$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \frac{(x-1)}{2^{x}}$

Comment: Asked zillion times. Try $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}a_x=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}a_{x+1}$ and see the connection.

Comment: Your series is a minor modification of a special case of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty na^n$; the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn) illustrate a considerable variety of approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty (x-1)y^x={d\over dy}\sum_{x=1}^\infty y^{x+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

because all the summands are nonnegative you can actually rearrange the sum like this:$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{x-1}{2^x}= \sum_{k=2}^\infty \underbrace{ \sum_{x=k}^\infty \frac{1}{2^x}}_{=\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Start with (for $\lvert u \rvert < 1$ the geometric series converges absolutely, we'll use $u = 1/2$ in the end, so all the manhandling is justified):

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{x \ge 1} u^x
    &= \frac{u}{1 - u} \\
  \frac{d}{d u} \sum_{x \ge 1} u^x
    &= \frac{1}{(1 - u)^2} \\
  \sum_{x \ge 1} x u^{x - 1}
    &= \\
  \sum_{x \ge 1} x u^x
    &= \frac{u}{(1 - u)^2} \\
  \sum_{x \ge 1} (x - 1) u^x
    &= \frac{u}{(1 - u)^2} - \frac{u}{1 - u} \\
    &= \frac{u^2}{(1 - u)^2}
\end{align*}$

Now replace $u = 1/2$ and get:

$\begin{align*}
  \sum_{x \ge 1} \frac{x - 1}{2^x}
    &= \frac{(1/2)^2}{(1 - 1/2)^2} \\
    &= 1
\end{align*}$